# Logstash Grok find source for _grokparsefailure

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

This is how I try to find the source of `_grokparsefailure`

> echo '<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id="0003"
> severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access"
> action="pass" method="CONNECT" srcip="10.134.240.227" dstip="" user=""
> group="" ad_domain="" statuscode="407" cached="0"
> profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)"
> filteraction=" ()" size="2505" request="0x20cc5800"
> url="https://vcsa.vmware.com/" referer="" error="" authtime="1"
> dnstime="0" aptptime="0" cattime="0" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="201"
> device="3" auth="1" ua="Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)"
> exceptions="url,ssl,certcheck,certdate"' |
> /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f
> /etc/logstash/conf.d/10-utm.stdin.test  --debug

10-utm.stdin.test:

```
# This is a Grok Pattern form Sophos SG UTM Log's
input { stdin { } }
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }

filter {
  grok {
    add_tag => [ "Line7" ]
  }  
  if "sophos-utm" in [tags] {
    grok {
      add_tag => [ "Line11" ]
      break_on_match => true
      match => ["message",'<%{INT:utm_syslog_pri}>(?:%{YEAR}):(%{MONTHNUM}):(?:%{MONTHDAY})-(?:%{HOUR}):(?:%{MINUTE}):(?:%{SECOND}) (?:%{SYSLOGHOST}) (?:%{SYSLOGPROG}): id=\"%{INT:utm_id}\" .* sub=\"%{DATA:utm_sub}\"']
      match => ["message",'<%{INT:utm_syslog_pri}>(?:%{YEAR}):(%{MONTHNUM}):(?:%{MONTHDAY})-(?:%{HOUR}):(?:%{MINUTE}):(?:%{SECOND}) (?:%{SYSLOGHOST}) (?:%{SYSLOGPROG}): id=\"%{INT:utm_id}\"']
      match => ["message",'<%{INT:utm_syslog_pri}>(?:%{YEAR}):(%{MONTHNUM}):(?:%{MONTHDAY})-(?:%{HOUR}):(?:%{MINUTE}):(?:%{SECOND}) (?:%{SYSLOGHOST}) (?:%{SYSLOGPROG}): \[%{DATA:utm_security2}:.*\]']
      match => ["message",'<%{INT:utm_syslog_pri}>(?:%{YEAR}):(%{MONTHNUM}):(?:%{MONTHDAY})-(?:%{HOUR}):(?:%{MINUTE}):(?:%{SECOND}) (?:%{SYSLOGHOST}) (?:%{SYSLOGPROG}):']
      
             overwrite => ["MONTHNUM", "MONTHDAY", "HOUR", "MINUTE", "SECOND", "SYSLOGHOST", "SYSLOGPROG", "id"]
             #tag_on_failure => []
     }
    grok {
      add_tag => [ "Line22" ]
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      grok {
        add_tag => [ "Line26" ]
      }
    }
    if [process][name] == "httpd" {
      if [utm_security2] {
        grok {
          match => ["message",'.*\[client %{IP:utm_srcip}\].* \[msg \"%{DATA:utm_msg}\"\].* \[data \"%{DATA:utm_data}\"\].* \[severity \"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\"\].* \[tag \"OWASP_TOP_10/%{DATA:utm_owasptop10}\"\].* \[hostname \"%{DATA:utm_hostname}\"\].* \[uri \"%{DATA:utm_uri}\"\]']
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A1" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Injection (SQL,OS,XXE,LDAP)"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A2" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Broken Authentification and Session Management"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A3" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Cross-Site Scripting"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A4" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Broken Access Control"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A5" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Security Misconfiguration"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A6" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Sensitive Data Exposure"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A7" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Insufficient Attack Protection"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A8" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A9" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Using Component with Know Vulnerabilities"]
          }
        }
        if [utm_owasptop10] == "A10" {
          mutate {
            replace => ["utm_owasptop10","Underprotected APIs (SOAP,REST,RPC,GWT)"]
          }
        }
      } else {
        grok {
          match => ["message",'.* srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\" localip=\"%{IP:utm_localip}\" size=\"%{INT:utm_size}\" user=\"%{DATA:utm_user}\" host=\"%{IP:utm_host}\" method=\"%{DATA:utm_method}\" statuscode=\"%{INT:utm_statuscode}\" reason=\"%{DATA:utm_reason}\" extra=\"%{DATA:utm_extra}\" exceptions=\"%{DATA:utm_exceptions}\" time=\"%{INT:utm_time}\" url=\"%{DATA:utm_url}\" server=\"%{DATA:utm_server}\" port=\"%{DATA:utm_port}\" query=\"%{DATA:utm_query}\" referer=\"%{DATA:utm_referer}\"']
        }
      }
      # Find the GeoLite Database here : https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/
      geoip {
        source => "utm_srcip"
        target => "geoip"
        database => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
      }
      mutate {
        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
      }

    }

    if [process][name] == "httpproxy" {
      grok {
#        match => ["message",'.* (?:severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\") (?:sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\") (?:sub=\"%{DATA}\") (?:name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\") (?:action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\") ?(?:method=\"%{DATA:utm_method}?\")? (?:srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}?\") (?:dstip=\"%{IP:utm_dstip}?\") (?:user=\"%{DATA:utm_user}?\") (?:group=\"%{DATA:utm_group}?\") (?:ad_domain=\"%{DATA:utm_ad_domain}?\") (?:statuscode=\"%{INT:utm_satuscode}?\") (?:cached=\"%{INT:utm_cached}?\") (?:profile=\"%{DATA:utm_profil}?\") (?:filteraction=\"%{DATA:utm_filteraction}?\") (?:size=\"%{INT:utm_size}?\") (?:request=\"%{DATA:utm_request}?\") (?:url=\"%{DATA:utm_url}?\") ?(?:referer=\"%{DATA:utm_referer}?\") ?(?:error=\"%{DATA:utm_error}?\") ?(?:authtime=\"%{DATA:utm_authtime}?\") ?(?:dnstime=\"%{INT:utm_dnstime}?\") ?(?:aptptime=\"%{INT:utm_aptptime}?\") ?(?:cattime=\"%{INT:utm_cattime}?\") ?(?:avscantime=\"%{INT:utm_avscantime}?\")? ?(?:fullreqtime=\"%{INT:utm_fullreqtime}?\")? ?(?:device=\"%{INT:utm_device}?\")? ?(?:auth=\"%{INT:utm_auth}?\")? ?(?:ua=\"%{DATA:utm_ua}?\")? ?(?:exceptions=\"%{DATA:utm_exceptions}?\")? ?(?:application=\"%{DATA:utm_application}?\")? ?(?:app-id=\"%{INT:utm_app-id}?\")? ?(?:category=\"%{DATA:utm_category}?\")? ?(?:reputation=\"%{DATA:utm_reputation}?\")? ?(?:categoryname=\"%{DATA:utm_categoryname}?\")? ?(?:sandbox=\"%{DATA:utm_sandbox}?\")?']
        match => ["message",'(?:severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\") (?:sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\") (?:sub=\"%{DATA:utm_sub}\") (?:name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\") (?:action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\") ?(?:method=\"%{DATA:utm_method}?\")? (?:srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}?\") (?:dstip=\"%{IP:utm_dstip}?\") (?:user=\"%{DATA:utm_user}?\") (?:group=\"%{DATA:utm_group}?\") (?:ad_domain=\"%{DATA:utm_ad_domain}?\") (?:statuscode=\"%{INT:utm_satuscode}?\") (?:cached=\"%{INT:utm_cached}?\") (?:profile=\"%{DATA:utm_profil}?\") (?:filteraction=\"%{DATA:utm_filteraction}?\") (?:size=\"%{INT:utm_size}?\") (?:request=\"%{DATA:utm_request}?\") (?:url=\"%{URI:utm_url}?\") ?(?:referer=\"%{URI:utm_referer}?\") ?(?:error=\"%{DATA:utm_error}?\") ?(?:authtime=\"%{DATA:utm_authtime}?\") ?(?:dnstime=\"%{INT:utm_dnstime}?\") ?(?:aptptime=\"%{INT:utm_aptptime}?\") ?(?:cattime=\"%{INT:utm_cattime}?\") ?(?:avscantime=\"%{INT:utm_avscantime}?\")? ?(?:fullreqtime=\"%{INT:utm_fullreqtime}?\")? ?(?:device=\"%{INT:utm_device}?\")? ?(?:auth=\"%{INT:utm_auth}?\")? ?(?:ua=\"%{DATA:utm_ua}?\")? ?(?:exceptions=\"%{DATA:utm_exceptions}?\")? ?(?:application=\"%{DATA:utm_application}?\")? ?(?:app-id=\"%{INT:utm_app-id}?\")? ?(?:category=\"%{DATA:utm_category}?\")? ?(?:reputation=\"%{DATA:utm_reputation}?\")? ?(?:categoryname=\"%{DATA:utm_categoryname}?\")? ?(?:sandbox=\"%{DATA:utm_sandbox}?\")? ?(?:country=\"%{DATA:utm_country}?\")? ?(?:content-type=\"%{DATA:utm_content_type}?\")?']
        match => ['utm_url','\.(?<utm_domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$']
        add_tag => [ "Line108" ]
      }
      if [utm_categoryname] == "Search Engines" {
        grok {
          match => ["utm_url", '.*q=(?<utm_search>[^$#&]+)(|[$#&].*)']
        }
        urldecode {
          field => "utm_search"
        }
        mutate {
          gsub => ["utm_search","\+"," "]
        }
      }
      if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        grok {
          add_tag => [ "Line123" ]
        }
      }      
      #dns {
      #    reverse => ["utm_srcip"]
      #    action => "replace"
      #    }
    }

    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      grok {
        add_tag => [ "Line134" ]
      }
    }
    if [process][name] == "snort" {
      grok {
        match => ["message", '.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA:utm_sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\" action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\" reason=\"%{DATA:utm_reason}\" srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\" dstip=\"%{DATA:utm_dstip}\" srcport=\"%{INT:utm_srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:utm_dstport}\" sid=\"%{DATA:utm_sid_snort}\" class=\"%{DATA:utm_class}\"']
      }
      geoip {
        source => "utm_srcip"
        target => "geoip"
        database => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
      }
      mutate {
        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
      }
    }

    if [process][name] == "ulogd" {
      if [utm_sub] == "ips" {
        grok {
          match => ["message", '.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA:utm_sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\" (action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\") reason=\"%{DATA:utm_reason}\" group=\"%{DATA:utm_group}\" srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\" dstip=\"%{DATA:utm_dstip}\" proto=\"%{INT:utm_proto}\" srcport=\"%{INT:utm_srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:utm_dstport}\" sid=\"%{DATA:utm_sid_snort}\" class=\"%{DATA:utm_class}\"']
          match => ["message",'.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA:utm_sub}\" name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\" action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:utm_fwrule}\" initf=\"%{DATA:utm_initf}\" srcmac=\"%{MAC:utm_srcmac}\" dstmac=\"%{MAC:utm_dstmac}\" srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\" dstip=\"%{IP:utm_dstip}\".* (srcport=\"%{INT:utm_srcport}\")?.* (dstport=\"%{INT:utm_dstport}\")?']
        }
      }

      if [utm_sub] == "packetfilter" {
        grok {
          match => ["message", '.* sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA}\" name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\" action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\" fwrule=\"%{INT:utm_fwrule}\" ?(initf=\"%{DATA:utm_initf}\")? ?(outitf=\"%{DATA:utm_outif}\")? ?(srcmac=\"%{MAC:utm_srcmac}\")? ?(dstmac=\"%{MAC:utm_dstmac}\")? srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\" dstip=\"%{IP:utm_dstip}\" proto=\"%{INT:utm_protocol}\" length=\"%{INT:utm_ulogd_pkglength}\" tos=\"%{DATA:utm_ulogd_tos}\" prec=\"%{DATA:utm_ulogd_prec}\" ttl=\"%{INT:utm_ttl}\" srcport=\"%{INT:utm_srcport}\" dstport=\"%{INT:utm_dstport}\" ?(tcpflags=\"%{DATA:utm_tcpflags}\")? ?(info=\"%{DATA:utm_info}\")?']
        }
      }
    }

    if [process][name] == "awelogger" {
      grok {
        match => ["message", '.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA}\" name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\" ssid=\"%{DATA:utm_ssid}\".* bssid=\"%{MAC:utm_bssid}\"']
      }
    }

    if [process][name] == "awed" {
      grok {
        match => ["message", '.* \[{%DATA:utm_ap}\] .* from %{IP:utm_srcip}:%{INT:utm_port}']
      }
    }

    #if [process][name] == "hostapd" {
    #  grok {
    #   match => ["message", '.*: {%DATA:utm_intf}: .* from %{IP:utm_srcip}:%{INT:utm_port}']
    #  }
    #}

    if [process][name] in ["openvpn", "pppd-l2tp"] {
      grok {
       match => ["message", '.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA}\" event=\"%{DATA:utm_event}\" username=\"%{DATA:utm_username}\" variant=\"%{DATA:utm_variant}\" srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\".* virtual_ip=\"%{IP:utm_virtual_ip}\"']
      }
      geoip {
        source => "utm_srcip"
        target => "geoip"
        database => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/data/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
      }
      mutate {
        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
      }
    }

    if [process][name] == "pluto" {
      grok {
        match => ["message", '.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA}\" event=\"%{DATA:utm_event}\" variant=\"%{DATA:utm_variant}\" connection=\"%{DATA:utm_connection}\" address=\"%{IP:utm_address}\" local_net=\"%{DATA:utm_local_net}\" remote_net=\"%{DATA:utm_remote_net}\"']
      }
    }


    if [process][name] == "afcd" {
      grok {
        match => ["message", '.* severity=\"%{LOGLEVEL:utm_severity}\" sys=\"%{DATA:utm_sys}\" sub=\"%{DATA}\" name=\"%{DATA:utm_name}\" srcip=\"%{IP:utm_srcip}\" dstip=\"%{IP:utm_dstip}\" .* threatname=\"%{DATA:utm_threatname}\" .* host=\"%{DATA:utm_host}\" .* action=\"%{DATA:utm_action}\"']
      }
    }

    mutate {
      replace => ["type","sophosutm"]
      add_field => ["utm_size_number","%{utm_size}"]
    }

    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      grok {
        add_tag => [ "Line222" ]
      }
    }    
    mutate {
      convert => {"utm_size_number" => "integer"}
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      grok {
        add_tag => [ "Line230" ]
      }
    }        
 }
}
```

I think this is where the Tag gets added, but I have no clue why

```
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.531 [[main]>worker1] grok - Running grok filter {:event=>{"@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>2022-10-24T14:01:31.415658841Z, "message"=>"<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id=\"0003\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureWeb\" sub=\"http\" name=\"http access\" action=\"pass\" method=\"CONNECT\" srcip=\"10.134.240.227\" dstip=\"\" user=\"\" group=\"\" ad_domain=\"\" statuscode=\"407\" cached=\"0\" profile=\"REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)\" filteraction=\" ()\" size=\"2505\" request=\"0x20cc5800\" url=\"https://vcsa.vmware.com/\" referer=\"\" error=\"\" authtime=\"1\" dnstime=\"0\" aptptime=\"0\" cattime=\"0\" avscantime=\"0\" fullreqtime=\"201\" device=\"3\" auth=\"1\" ua=\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)\" exceptions=\"url,ssl,certcheck,certdate\"", "host"=>{"hostname"=>"elk-1-test"}, "event"=>{"original"=>"<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id=\"0003\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureWeb\" sub=\"http\" name=\"http access\" action=\"pass\" method=\"CONNECT\" srcip=\"10.134.240.227\" dstip=\"\" user=\"\" group=\"\" ad_domain=\"\" statuscode=\"407\" cached=\"0\" profile=\"REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)\" filteraction=\" ()\" size=\"2505\" request=\"0x20cc5800\" url=\"https://vcsa.vmware.com/\" referer=\"\" error=\"\" authtime=\"1\" dnstime=\"0\" aptptime=\"0\" cattime=\"0\" avscantime=\"0\" fullreqtime=\"201\" device=\"3\" auth=\"1\" ua=\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)\" exceptions=\"url,ssl,certcheck,certdate\""}}}
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.532 [[main]>worker1] grok - Event now:  {:event=>{"@version"=>"1", "message"=>"<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id=\"0003\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureWeb\" sub=\"http\" name=\"http access\" action=\"pass\" method=\"CONNECT\" srcip=\"10.134.240.227\" dstip=\"\" user=\"\" group=\"\" ad_domain=\"\" statuscode=\"407\" cached=\"0\" profile=\"REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)\" filteraction=\" ()\" size=\"2505\" request=\"0x20cc5800\" url=\"https://vcsa.vmware.com/\" referer=\"\" error=\"\" authtime=\"1\" dnstime=\"0\" aptptime=\"0\" cattime=\"0\" avscantime=\"0\" fullreqtime=\"201\" device=\"3\" auth=\"1\" ua=\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)\" exceptions=\"url,ssl,certcheck,certdate\"", "@timestamp"=>2022-10-24T14:01:31.415658841Z, "host"=>{"hostname"=>"elk-1-test"}, "tags"=>["_grokparsefailure"], "event"=>{"original"=>"<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id=\"0003\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureWeb\" sub=\"http\" name=\"http access\" action=\"pass\" method=\"CONNECT\" srcip=\"10.134.240.227\" dstip=\"\" user=\"\" group=\"\" ad_domain=\"\" statuscode=\"407\" cached=\"0\" profile=\"REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)\" filteraction=\" ()\" size=\"2505\" request=\"0x20cc5800\" url=\"https://vcsa.vmware.com/\" referer=\"\" error=\"\" authtime=\"1\" dnstime=\"0\" aptptime=\"0\" cattime=\"0\" avscantime=\"0\" fullreqtime=\"201\" device=\"3\" auth=\"1\" ua=\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)\" exceptions=\"url,ssl,certcheck,certdate\""}}}
{
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id=\"0003\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureWeb\" sub=\"http\" name=\"http access\" action=\"pass\" method=\"CONNECT\" srcip=\"10.134.240.227\" dstip=\"\" user=\"\" group=\"\" ad_domain=\"\" statuscode=\"407\" cached=\"0\" profile=\"REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)\" filteraction=\" ()\" size=\"2505\" request=\"0x20cc5800\" url=\"https://vcsa.vmware.com/\" referer=\"\" error=\"\" authtime=\"1\" dnstime=\"0\" aptptime=\"0\" cattime=\"0\" avscantime=\"0\" fullreqtime=\"201\" device=\"3\" auth=\"1\" ua=\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)\" exceptions=\"url,ssl,certcheck,certdate\"",
    "@timestamp" => 2022-10-24T14:01:31.415658841Z,
          "host" => {
        "hostname" => "elk-1-test"
    },
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ],
         "event" => {
        "original" => "<30>2022:10:24-15:08:28 utm-1 httpproxy[28052]: id=\"0003\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureWeb\" sub=\"http\" name=\"http access\" action=\"pass\" method=\"CONNECT\" srcip=\"10.134.240.227\" dstip=\"\" user=\"\" group=\"\" ad_domain=\"\" statuscode=\"407\" cached=\"0\" profile=\"REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)\" filteraction=\" ()\" size=\"2505\" request=\"0x20cc5800\" url=\"https://vcsa.vmware.com/\" referer=\"\" error=\"\" authtime=\"1\" dnstime=\"0\" aptptime=\"0\" cattime=\"0\" avscantime=\"0\" fullreqtime=\"201\" device=\"3\" auth=\"1\" ua=\"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_321)\" exceptions=\"url,ssl,certcheck,certdate\""
    }
}
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.671 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<LogStash::WorkerLoopThread:0x57397be3 dead>"}
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.671 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Shutdown waiting for worker thread {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<LogStash::WorkerLoopThread:0x56f4bfea dead>"}
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.672 [[main]-pipeline-manager] grok - Closing {:plugin=>"LogStash::Filters::Grok"}
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.673 [[main]-pipeline-manager] pluginmetadata - Removing metadata for plugin e489c8cb24e095cea22f0d0ea0836e8556029d1f12126d19d9dfbf7ecd8c43d1
[DEBUG] 2022-10-24 14:01:31.673 [[main]-pipeline-manager] grok - Closing {:plugin=>"LogStash::Filters::Grok"}
```

EDIT:
Thank you @Badger
This is working for me, to add a simple Tag for debugging

```
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    grok {
    match => ["message",'%{GREEDYDATA}']
    add_tag => [ "Line134-Fail" ]
    remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event does not have any tags, so your entire configuration is equivalent to

```
grok { add_tag => [ "Line7" ] }
```

which does add a "_grokparsefailure". That happens because the [match](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-grok/blob/64555883e55608123e1cf332b2326534768da409/lib/logstash/filters/grok.rb#L378) function defaults to failure, and if given an empty hash of matches to check it returns false.